# calculation of an average function

Tags: excel, vba

When I try the following syntax, it shows an error:
Either as non defined function or error defined by object/application.

I expect to see the average result of two cells value instead of error or undefined function.
The syntax I used for average calculation:

```
Range("G2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("A2:B2"))
Cells(G, 2).Value = Application.Average(A2,B2)

Sub stock_security()

    Dim A, B, D, sigma, h

    'condition de calcul de stock
    'If Sheets("Résultat").Range("F2").Value = "produit stable" Then

        'selection des cellules

        A = Sheets("Résultat").Range("D2").Value
        B = Sheets("Résultat").Range("C2").Value

        'calculer la moyenne de la demande
        Cells(G, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(A, B)    
        D = Cells(G, 2).Value

        'calcul du stock de securite de chaque cellule par la formule
        'Msgbx "Resultat de la moyenne est:" & D, 0, "Résultats"

        'calcul de l'ecarttype
        'sigma = eccarttype(D)

        'h = sigma / D

    'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: **TYPO** alert - it's **syntax** - not "syntaxe" ....

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(G, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(A, B)`

In your code `G` is not defined so `Cells` is going to throw an error as there is no cells with address (0,2).

Sub stock_security()

```
'Declare variable type for each variable
'Dim dblA As Double, dblB As Double, dblD As Double, sigma, h

'condition de calcul de stock
'If Sheets("Résultat").Range("F2").Value = "produit stable" Then
'selection des cellules

dblA = Range("D2").Value
dblB = Range("C2").Value

'calculer la moyenne de la demande
Cells(2, 7).Value = Application.Average(dblA, dblB)
dlbD = Cells(2, 7).Value

'calcul du stock de securite de chaque cellule par la formule
'Msgbx "Resultat de la moyenne est:" & D, 0, "Résultats"

'calcul de l'ecarttype
'sigma = eccarttype(D)

'h = sigma / D

'End If
```